# wrong mock_model in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

Here is the rspec code for create in controller:

```
describe "'create' successful" do
  before(:each) do

    @customer = mock_model(Customer)
    @customer.stub(:save).and_return(true) 

    session[:sales] =  true
    session[:user_id] = 1
    session[:user_name] = "sales.name"
    session[:page_step] = 1
    session['page1'] = customers_path
  end

  it "should create one customer record" do
    lambda do
      put 'create', @customer         
    end.should change(Customer, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "should redirect to customers path" do
    put 'create', @customer
    flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
    response.should redirect_to(customers_path)
  end
end
```

Here is the create in controller:

```
  def create

    if session[:sales]
      @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer], :as => :roles_new_update)
      @customer.sales_id = session[:user_id]
      if @customer.save
        @message = "New customer #{params[:name]} was created. Please check it out"
        @subject = "New customer #{params[:name]} was created BY {#session[:user_name]}"
        UserMailer.notify_tl_dh_ch_ceo(@message, @subject, session[:user_id])
        redirect_to session[('page' + session[:page_step].to_s).to_sym], :notice => 'Customer was created successfaully!'          
      else
        render 'new', :notice => 'Customer was not saved!'
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the error in rspec:

```
  1) CustomersController GET customer page 'create' successful should create one customer record
     Failure/Error: put 'create', @customer
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "1001":String
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:40:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:39:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) CustomersController GET customer page 'create' successful should redirect to customers path
     Failure/Error: put 'create', @customer
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "1002":String
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:45:i
```

The problem is with the mocking data of @customer. What's wrong with the mocking in spec?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong, you simply have to make your model fetch the mock you've created.

Proceed this way:

```
@customer = mock_model(Customer)
@customer.stub(:save).and_return(true) 
Customer.should_receive(:new).and_return(@customer)
```

---

Rereading your question I figured out that Rails could be complaining because when you pass a variable to your route, it should respond to `to_param`.

But your mock doesn't: it's nothing.

I'd say choose among the following:

- use a Factory which is a real ActiveRecord object with the right properties
- edit your test for something like `put 'create', 1234` or any integer you want.

BTW, `put` triggers the `update` action which is not supposed to created objects but simply change them.

Comment: Added Customer.should_receive(:new).and_return(@customer) as above. Same error.

Comment: Tried the following with post and it is the same error:   Customer.should_receive(:new).with({:name => 'test one', :short_name => 'test', :contact => 'guy', :cell => '123',
                                            :phone => '456', :address => 'wired address', :active => true,
                                            :category1_id => 1, :sales_id => 2, :email => 'test@wx.com' }).and_return(@customer)

Comment: Tried to use Factory for real data. Somehow the @customer.save does not return True so the lambda is not executed and caused the spec failure. I posted a question for this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867361/object-save-failed-in-spec-data-validation. Please take a look to see if there is anything wrong with the Factory. Thanks.

Comment: did you replace the `put` with a `post` ?